# GeoServer different styles for one layer?

Tags: geoserver, wms, style, filter

In GeoServer I have a layer created from a database table with the following structure:

> `tableX` ( `id`,`name`,`typeid`,`description`,`geom` )

The `geom` field is always a polygon. I also have created 3 different styles in GeoServer, basically 3 kind of polygons with different colours.

What I'm trying to do is to serve one WMS layer with different styles, filtering them by `typeid` field. So, if:

- `typeid = 1` I use the first style (Green polygon)
- `typeid = 2` I use the second style (Blue polygon)
- `typeid = 3` I use the third style (Red polygon)

> Is this possible in GeoServer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create 3 separate styles with a filter that selects only the features you want styled. Or you can create one style with 3 rules each with a filter to select the required filters.

In the first case, you will see only on type of polygons at a time (unless you request the layer more than once); in the second case you will see all three types of polygon coloured differently at the same time.